# Node.js: Better way to resolve Promise from another API

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose I have two APIs, the first API is called by the client. Then it will call a API on the storage server to store some data. The storage server will return an response immediately with status code 202.

```
app.post('/create/:requestId', (req, res) => {
  const { requestId } = req.params;
  // Call 3rd party API
  axios.post('/store', { id: requestId });
});
```

After the data is successfully stored, the storage service will call another API on the server as a webhook to notify us that the data is stored.:

```
app.post('/resolve/:requestId', (req, res) => {
   // Called by the storage server to notify the data is successfully stored

});
```

What I need is that, when the client calls `POST /create/:requestId`, it won't return until the data is successfully stored on the storage server. One way to do so is that:

```
const pendingRes = [];
app.post('/create/:requestId', async (req, res) => {
  const { requestId } = req.params;
  // Call 3rd party API
  const result = await axios.post('/store', { id: requestId });
  if (result.data.success) {
     pendingRes.push({ id: requestId, res });
  }
});

app.post('/resolve/:requestId', (req, res) => {
   // Called by the storage server to notify the data is successfully stored
  const { requestId }= req.params;
  const resToResolve = pendingRes.find(r => r.id === requestId);
  const idx = pendingRes.findIndex(r => r.id === requestId);
  if (resToResolve) {
    // Response to the create API
    resToResolve.res.json({ success: true });
    pendingRes.splice(idx, 1);
  }
  // Response to the resolve API
  res.json({ success: true });
});
```

I know this can solve the problem but I wonder if there is any better way to do that such as using Promise. I don't like this method because actually there are many similar APIs on the storage server and I need to create many arrays for saving pending res.

Of course, I cannot change the API on the storage server :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create and `await` a Promise which will be resolved at `/resolve/:requestId`.

```
const requestId2resolve = new Map();
app.post('/create/:requestId', async (req, res) => {
  const { requestId } = req.params;
  // Call 3rd party API
  const result = await axios.post('/store', { id: requestId });
  if (result.data.success) {
    await new Promise(resolve => requestId2resolve.set(requestId, resolve));
    res.json({ success: true });
  }
});

app.post('/resolve/:requestId', (req, res) => {
   // Called by the storage server to notify the data is successfully stored
  const { requestId }= req.params;
  if (requestId2resolve.has(requestId)) {
    const resolve = requestId2resolve.get(requestId);
    resolve();
    requestId2resolve.delete(requestId);
  }
  // Response to the resolve API
  res.json({ success: true });
});
```